# Forward email based on subject line

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I'm trying to forward emails from my company's Outlook to an email account outside of our company. I have been given the ok to do this.

I'd like to forward any email that contains "Excel Friday" in the subject line.

```vb
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items
Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Set olApp = Outlook.Application
    Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    ' default local Inbox
    Set Items = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
End Sub
 
Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem
    If TypeName(Item) = "MailItem" Then
        Set Msg = Item
        If Msg.Subject = "Excel Friday" Then
            Dim myMail As Outlook.MailItem
            Set myMail = Msg.Reply
            myMail.To = "xxxxxx@fakemail.com"
            myMail.Display
        End If
    End If
ProgramExit:
    Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    Resume ProgramExit
End Sub
```

Comment: FYI you can do this with a basic *Rules & Alerts* rule

Comment: Why do you need to use a VBA macro? Outlook allows to get the job done manually.

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to forward any email that contains "Excel Friday" in the subject line to another email address.

But in the code you check for the exact match of the subject line:

```
If Msg.Subject = "Excel Friday" Then
```

Instead you need to look for a substring. To find the position of a substring in a string, use **Instr** function.

```
If Instr(Msg.Subject, "Excel Friday") Then
```

Also I have noticed that you use the Reply method:

```
Set myMail = Msg.Reply
```

Use the [Forward](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865399.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method instead:

```
Set myMail = Msg.Forward
```

And then use the Send method.

```
 myMail.Recipients.Add "Eugene Astafiev" 

 myMail.Send
```

Be aware, the code is based on the [ItemAdd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869609.aspx) event handler. This event is not fired when a large number of items are added to the folder at once (more than 16).

Comment: Sorry I pasted one of my older iterations of the code (guess I didn't hit save).  I did have it changed to msg.forward and mymail.send

I've given the Instr a try and I am still not able to get it to work.  How do I know what folder is the "default" inbox that I have it searching?  Is it possible that what I consider the default inbox really isn't?  

Sorry I am just stepping into Outlook macros coming from the excel world so a lot of the outlook applications are new to me.

Comment: I'd suggest starting from the [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article in MSDN. Try to add `Debug.Print` statements to the code to see what happens under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a Run a Script rule

```
Sub ChangeSubjectForward(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
    Item.Subject = "Test"
 Item.Save

Set olForward = Item.Forward
olForward.Recipients.Add "Jasonfish11@domain.com"

olForward.Send

End Sub
```

If a vba you can run on all messages in a folder at any time.

Paste into ThisOutlookSession and run

```
Sub ChangeSubjectThenSend()
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim aItem As Object

Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set mail = olApp.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder

For Each aItem In mail.Items
      aItem.Subject = "New Subject"
    aItem.Save

    Set olForward = aItem.Forward
    olForward.Recipients.Add "Jasonfish11@domain.com"
    olForward.Send

Next aItem
End Sub
```

[source Link](http://forums.slipstick.com/threads/87770-creating-a-rule-that-both-forwards-the-original-attachment-and-uses-a-template/)